# Stuck on Build succeeded

Tags: heroku

Heruko isn't starting for me, it doesn't show any errors and it's just stuck on "Build succeeded"

**What I have tried:**

- Restart using "heroku restart worker.1 -a /app/"
- Pushed something into my github and it did try to restart but still stuck on Build succeeded

Im sorry if theres just a simple fix im new to Heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im dumb, I wrote Procfile with a lower case P